# Find the interpolation polynomial $P_n(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I would appreciate help with how to find the polynomial $P_n(x)$ for the question below:

Interpolate $f$ at equidistant points  $x_i=[-1,1]$ such that $x_i=\frac{2i}{n}-1$, $i={0,1,2,..,n}$ with a polynomial $P_n(x)$ of degree less or equal to n. Where, $$f=\frac{1}{1+25x^2}.$$

I was thinking about doing this for $P_4(x), P_8(x), P_{12}(x)$ and $P_{16}(x)$ and then construct four graphs all presenting $f$ and respective $P_n(x)$ to be able to compare these (kinda like they did [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ren105/cs314/Chapter4_CS314.pdf) on page 63). And my guess is that one should use $P(x)=p_1x^n+p_2^{n-1}+...+p_nx+p_{n+1}$ from the Weierstrass approximation theorem to get $P_n(x)$, but still from this I don't know how to construct the interpolation polynomial.

My thought is now that one can choose a polynomial that corresponds to P as long as it is less or equal to n? But then we won't use $x_i$ in this and therefore this must then be wrong.

Does anyone want to help me clarify how one should construct the interpolation polynomial $P_n(x)$?

**Edit** the example in the link above also construct $P_4(x), P_8(x), P_{12}(x)$ and $P_{16}(x)$ but never show how they did these, they only present them in the graphs, and therefore that example can't help me with this problem.

Comment: first of all note that f(x) is an even function, so the polynomial will contain only even powers of x

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just so I understand, if one would get $x^3+x^2+x-1$ the interpolation polynomial should be $x^2-1$

Comment: @kabin Other way around, you started with an even function on a symmetric interval with symmetric nodes, so the polynomial approximant will be an even polynomial. This doesn't really help you any in practice, the easiest methods (Lagrange or Newton) don't care about it.

Comment: @kabin: does not work in the way you say . Lan already explained the base concept. And it is true that Lagrange or Newton methods in their general formulation do not care about symmetry. However, their output shall be an even polynomial in $(x-0)=x$ (when using all the points symmetrical wrt $x=0$)

Comment: Thank you both! I looked into a few examples and did som practice and I think I finally get it. When I wrote my question earlier I had missed that n = 4 gives n + 1 values for x and y ​​respectively, hence I got an incorrect polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Lagrange interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial):

> Given $n+1$ points $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ with distinct $x$-coordinates, there exists a unique polynomial of degree at most $n$ that passes through all of the points, given by the formula
> $$P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}y_i\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{n+1}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}.$$

You can check for yourself that this polynomial will do the trick -- at $x_i$, all terms in the sum except for the $i$th term vanish, so the evaluation is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank you! I just have one question, do one use this for both global and local interpolation polynomial?

Comment: @kabin What do you mean "global"? An actual global polynomial approximant is by design not interpolatory, i.e. it is not designed to be equal to $f(x)$ at prespecified nodes. Anyway, if you're doing this on a computer the Lagrange method will probably fail in a quite dramatic way when $n$ is as large as $16$. Not because it's not mathematically correct but because it performs badly in approximate arithmetic. The Newton method has less of this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to ruin the surprise, but you'll see that these interpolating polynomials will start behaving quite badly as $n$ increases... This is known as Runge's example and it is normally used to motivate the use of Chebyshev nodes.